# Importing only certain rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am attempting to create a spreadsheet based off another spreadsheet. I only wish to import certain rows based on the second column of the first spreadsheet. If that column contains certain users Initials I want the rows to appear in the second spreadsheet.

The formula I am using is (I'm omitting the key):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key","Sheet1!A2:A3000"),"SELECT * WHERE COL2='JB'")
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Invalid query: Column [COLB] does not exist in table.

I have tried using different terminology for the second column - `COL2`, even the header name of the column. But nothing works. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your task is hopeless because when only importing a single column there is no second column. However querying say `Sheet1!A2:B3000` instead will still not work with `COL2` because that is case sensitive, just like column `b` selection does not work in a query in place of `B`. Maybe try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key","Sheet1!A2:B3000"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2='JB'")
```